# A tool to convert Python into human readable Go code which still needs manual tuning

Tags: python, go, converter

Is there a library/tool to convert python code into readable go code which needs manual adjustment after conversion.

What I am looking for is a library/tool which can do partial semi-automatic conversion of python code into **readable** go code. Its totally fine that the converted code will need human corrections/adjustments afterwards.

Have checked [grumpy](https://github.com/google/grumpy), but its a dead project and the code is not readable after conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such tool is [pytogo](https://gitlab.com/esr/pytogo/-/tree/master/)

According to its readme

> pytogo is a fast, crude, incomplete Python-to-Go translator meant to
>   assist a human programmer in translating large volumes of Python to
>   idiomatic Go, preserving comments and structure. It does the
>   mechanical things that are easy for software but hard for humans,
>   leaving a human free to concentrate on the hard parts like type
>   annotations.

Comment: If there is no better answer after a few days, please accept your own, as that will help others who read this question in future

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica yes I will